# Converting canvas to image does not include images on the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I want to convert a canvas to a png image and put it on a page. My problem is that if I have an image on my canvas, it does not get converted. This is my HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='UTF-8'>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/css/general.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="./codetests.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="wrapper" id="wrap1">

            <img id="persphoto" src="./images/nouserimage.png" style="display:none;">

            <input type="hidden" id="persname" value="Test Testinen">
            <input type="hidden" id="adress" value="Testgatan 1">
            <input type="hidden" id="postaddr" value="12345 Teststad">
            <input type="hidden" id="homephone" value="0123456789">
            <input type="hidden" id="cellphone" value="0712345678">

            <canvas src="" id="canvasresult" width="296px" height="420px" />
            <br>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript"> drawCanvas(); </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> convertCanvasToImage(canvasresult); </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My JavaScript is the following:

```
// Converts canvas to an image
function convertCanvasToImage(canvas) {
    var image = new Image();

    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    //return image;

    document.getElementById("wrap1").appendChild(image);
}

function drawCanvas() {
    var c = document.getElementById("canvasresult");

    h=parseInt(document.getElementById("canvasresult").getAttribute("height"));
    w=parseInt(document.getElementById("canvasresult").getAttribute("width"));

    //get context
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    //Fill the path
    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,w,h);

    var img=document.getElementById("persphoto");
    ih=parseInt(document.getElementById("persphoto").getAttribute("height"));
    iw=parseInt(document.getElementById("persphoto").getAttribute("width"));

    var maxw = 150;
    var maxh = 150;

    if (ih > iw) {
        var newh = 150;
        var neww = Math.round(150 * (iw / ih));
    } else if (ih < iw) {
        var newh = Math.round(150 * (ih / iw));
        var neww = 150;
    } else {
        var newh = 150;
        var neww = 150;
    }

    var newx = Math.round((296 - neww) / 2);
    var newy = 60 + Math.round((150 - newh) / 2);

    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img,newx,newy,neww,newh);
    };


    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.font = '10pt Verdana';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("persname").value, w/2, h*0.65);
    ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("adress").value, w/2, h*0.69);
    ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("postaddr").value, w/2, h*0.73);
    ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("homephone").value, w/2, h*0.77);
    ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("cellphone").value, w/2, h*0.81);


    var canvasData = c.toDataURL("image/png");
    /*
    document.getElementById("canvasdata").value = canvasData;
    document.getElementById("hidepersphoto").value = document.getElementById("persphoto").value;
    document.getElementById("hidepersname").value = document.getElementById("persname").value;
    document.getElementById("hideadress").value = document.getElementById("adress").value;
    document.getElementById("hidepostaddr").value = document.getElementById("postaddr").value;
    document.getElementById("hidehomephone").value = document.getElementById("homephone").value;
    document.getElementById("hidecellphone").value = document.getElementById("cellphone").value;
    */
}
```

My problem is as I said that when I call `convertCanvasToImage` any images currently on the canvas doesn't get converted. The result is:

[image]

Can anyone spot where the problem is?

Comment: Have you run this without the `display: none` style on the image?

Comment: @steveukx Yes I have, it didn't make any difference except that the image was visible...

Comment: What is `canvasresult` in this context... `convertCanvasToImage(canvasresult);` ?

Comment: @w3d It is the id of the canvas.

Comment: Although your function expects an object?

Comment: @w3d I didn't know that, so I guess either my function or my function call is crap...

Comment: Well, you appear to be passing a variable called `canvasresult` (which you say contains the `id` of the canvas - a string - although this is not set in the code you have posted) to your `convertCanvasToImage()` function. But in that function you are calling `canvas.toDataURL()` - a method of the canvas _object_. It looks like you are trying to access the HTML element in the "globalscope", by referencing it directly (rather can calling `getElementById()`) - which is prone to error. Although you say this is working to some extent - you are getting an image with something from the canvas on it?

Answer (score 1):

Few Changes:

pass the string literal `"canvasresult"` of canvasId rather than a variable.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> convertCanvasToImage("canvasresult"); </script>
```

Get the canvas object based on the Id:

```
// Converts canvas to an image
function convertCanvasToImage(canvasId) {
    var image = new Image();
    var canvas=document.getElementById(canvasId);

    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    //return image;

    document.getElementById("wrap1").appendChild(image);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` on this line: `image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");`

Comment: @BluePrint In what browser are you getting that error? I would guess that it's not finding the canvas element whose ID is passed to the function (which would suggest you are not passing `"canvasresult"` as in Vijay's code), however, the error is not necessarily what I would have expected in this case (In WebKit you'd get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toDataURL' of null`).

Comment: could you please post a jsfiddle example, It would be more easy to replicate and correct the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for all help. However, I went around the problem by creating the canvas image on a totally different page and storing it on the server and then displaying it on the page I wanted to, I still don't know what was wrong, but I'll stick to this working solution.